algorithm to find all the combinations of the layout
There are 3 different components in a rectangle:

The size of the components doesn't matter, like No.1 and No.2 in the above image are the same.
The three other images below represent different arrangements, however.
Now I need to find all the combinations of the layout. I just have no clue.
How can I determine all of them?
I thought of using arrays, but I still don't know how to make it work.

It feels like a school assignment

Hint: Consider that a "layout" is a list of "rows", and a "row" is a list of colours. You want to find all the ways to group your three colours into rows.

Can you at least say what the correct answer is for the case in the image that you posted? And can you explain why that answer is correct?

Is there no layout that has one color filling the whole left side, while the other two colors are stacked at the right side? Is there no layout where the colors are spread into three columns? Why not?

Any feedback on above comments?

The layouts are determined by two variables:

The structure of the layout (without coloring)
The distribution of three colors into a layout

Structure
The structure must always be split by a first line across the container. This can be either:

A vertical line, splitting the container into two columns
A horizontal line, splitting the container into two rows (as in your example)

Then a second line is used to make a split, which can be either:

Parallel to the first line
Orthogonal to the first line, splitting the first half
Orthogonal to the first line, splitting the second half

So there are 2x3=6 possible structures (without coloring):

Coloring
We can choose an area for coloring red: 3 possibilities. We can choose a remaining area for coloring green: 2 possibilities. The remaining area will get the yellow color. So there are 3x2 possibilities to color the structure, and this can be done for each of the above 6 structures, leading to 6x6=36 possibilities:

Algorithm
The above describes what you could do. A number between 0 and 35 could uniquely identify each layout. Or you could reserve 6 numbers for identifying one of the 6 structures, and 6 for the coloring scheme. Then a pair of [structureId, colorSchemeId] would uniquely identify one of the above layouts. Or you could split it into even more detail, like:
{
    isFirstLineVertical: boolean,
    isSecondLineParallel: boolean,
    isFirstHalfSplit: boolean, // Ignored when preceding boolean is true
    colorArrangement: string // One of "rgy", "ryg", "gry", "yrg", "gyr", "ygr" 
}

And we can imagine lots of other structures to represent all 36 possibilities. Pick one that suits you best.
Visualisation
How you structure it is really not that relevant. Once you decide how to somehow render it, you could make a choice for maybe building a string.
Like something that looks like the above image when printed. One such a string could consist of letters "R" and "G" and "Y" to denote a "pixel" color, and the string would have newline characters to form rectangular shapes (they would be 6 characters wide and 6 character high to make them all uniform). For example, the first colored layout could then print like this:
RRRRRR
RRRRRR
GGGGGG
GGGGGG
YYYYYY
YYYYYY

Here is an implementation in a runnable JavaScript snippet that does that:


function display(colors, vertical, parallel, splitFirst) {
    let s;
    if (parallel) {
        s = colors.map(color => (color.repeat(6) + "\n").repeat(2)).join("");
    } else {
        s = (colors[0].repeat(6) + "\n").repeat(3) +
            (colors[1].repeat(3) + colors[2].repeat(3) + "\n").repeat(3);
        if (splitFirst) s = s.slice(21) + s.slice(0, 21); // Swap top/bottom
    }
    if (vertical) { // transpose (diagonal mirror)
        let s2 = s;
        s = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                s += s2[j*7+i];
            }
            s += "\n";
        }
    }
    console.log(s + "\n");
}

for (let color1 of "RGY") {
    for (let color2 of "RGY".replace(color1, "")) {
        let colors = [color1, color2, "RGY".replace(color1, "").replace(color2, "")];
        for (let vertical of [false, true]) {
            for (let parallel of [false, true]) {
                display(colors, vertical, parallel, false);
                if (!parallel) display(colors, vertical, false, true);
            }
        }        
    }
}




This is absolutely causing that optical illusion

Hadn't noticed it, but yes... :-D

Wow, thank you so much! I wonder if this solution still works when it comes to 4, 5 or more components
